# Start barplot from axis maximum

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am constructing a barplot in log scale :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

data <- matrix(c("2%","A", 0.00013, 4.94e-06, "6%", "A", 1.7e-05, 7.95e-06, "2%", "B", 3.1e-06, 1.50e-07, "6%", "B", 6.8e-07, 5.04e-07), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
data <- as.data.frame(data); colnames(data) = c("P", "variable", "value", "sd")
data$value <- as.numeric(as.character(data$value)); data$sd <- as.numeric(as.character(data$sd))

plot <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=P, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black", size = 1, width = 0.5, position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2%", "6%")) + scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x)) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value, ymax=sd), size=1, width=0.25, position=position_dodge(0.5))
plot
```

[image: graph obtained with my code]

However, my kind of data is usually represented differently in my field. I need to create the same histogram, but where the barplot would start from the other side of the x-axis, just above the x-axis labels, like this:

[image]

I know it doesn't really make sense to represent it like this, but it is how I have to do it (because I want to show that A is actually doing a better job than B, which might be not apparant at first glance on the first graph). Maybe it's not possible at all using ggplot2, as this doesn't suit ggplot2's logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd tolerate a warning, you can play with `after_scale()` to set the `ymax` value of the rectangle that you're drawing.

However, you'd need to think carefully about what you're doing to the `sd` variable and what it means to log-transform that value (especially when it is the standard devation).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

data <- matrix(c("2%","A", 0.00013, 4.94e-06, "6%", "A", 1.7e-05, 7.95e-06, "2%", "B", 3.1e-06, 1.50e-07, "6%", "B", 6.8e-07, 5.04e-07), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
data <- as.data.frame(data); colnames(data) = c("P", "variable", "value", "sd")
data$value <- as.numeric(as.character(data$value)); data$sd <- as.numeric(as.character(data$sd))

plot <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=P, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black", size = 1, width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(),
           aes(ymax = after_scale(-Inf))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("2%", "6%")) + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x)) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value, ymax=sd), size=1, width=0.25, position=position_dodge(0.5))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymax
plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistsake on the type of graph. I think this works for me, I'm just looking for a way to get this graphical output. Any tip on how to deal with the sd with such a graph, which indeed is a standart deviation ?

Comment: You can calculate the standard devation in the log-transformed space and just mention, in the figure legend or somewhere, that is the standard deviation under lognormal assumptions (i.e. the `sdlog` parameter in `rlnorm()` for example).